# Upsert Mongoose Error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm pretty new to Mongoose/Mongo and node.js, so I suspect this is just a misunderstanding on my side, I have some problem when I try to upsert my object.
 
Here What have I try to use upsert in my code :

```
  app.post("/api/orders/:id", async (req, res) => {
    const { id, name, email, phone, data, item } = req.body;
    const existingVisitor = await Visitor.findOne({ email: email.trim() });
    if(existingVisitor){
      delete Visitor._id;
    }
    const OrderSchema = await new Order({
      orderDate: new Date(),
      item: item
    });

    const visitor = await new Visitor(
      { email: email.trim() },
      {
        name: name,
        email: email.trim(),
        phone: phone,
        data: data,
        createDate: new Date(),
        _user: req.params.id,
        order: [OrderSchema]
      },
      { upsert: true, setDefaultsOnInsert: true }
    );
    try {
      await visitor.update();
      console.log("Sucess!");
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(422).send(err);
    }
```

When I'm Trying to test it in Postman, I got error result following error : **After applying the update to the document {_id: ObjectId('59f1896ccabc4f12bc17e5c6') , ...}, the (immutable) field '_id' was found to have been altered to _id: null** 
What should I do to fix that error?

Comment: That's the wrong usage of `.update()` in this case you simply want `.save()` or `.create()`. Spending some time with the [mongoose documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html) and probably more specifically a familarity with [MongoDB CRUD in general](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/crud/) is something I would really recommend for you. The latter in particular should give you a bit more guide into "which" methods and arguments are applied for the different operations.

Comment: @NeilLunn Why i can't use update? I use update because if there's no result in collection it will insert new document. If i use insert it'll create a duplicate document with the same email

Comment: I did not say you "could not use it", but rather that your "usage" is incorrect here. You don't make a "new" instance and then call `.update()`. What I did suggest you do is actually read some documentation, rather than garnering from snippets of code you have seen that you clearly do not understand. Read the Manual. It's where you should start before asking questions here.